# how to find text cut off while resizing td element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have resize option in my table. When I resize, it cuts off some text. How would I find the size at which the text begins to cut off..

[image]

When I resize the  header this happens[image]

Comment: i think you need to give min width

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to multiply the length of the string by the point size times 1.25. This should give you how wide your areas should be FOR THE TITLE and not the text that goes into those slots.

So strlen(text)*fontPointSize*1.25

Also - as Yo Yo has said - you need to specify the width of the field.  Like so:

```
<td width='123px'>TITLE</td>
```

Comment: @farookjm : Right.  That's why you have to recalculate it each time it changes and then adjust the width accordingly.  All you need is the onresize option set or maybe the onchange trigger.